# How to use JAXB to generate XML document without XML root element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Sometimes I would like to generate the XML document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<properties>
</properties>
<context>
</context>
```

Do not with root elment, not like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <root>
     <properties>
     </properties>
     <context>
     </context>
 </root>
```

Here is my Class:

```
//@XmlRootElement(name="root")
public class WithoutRootElement {

    private String properties;
    Private String context;

    @XmlElement(name="properties")
    public String getProperties() {...}

    @XmlElement(name="context")
    public String getContext() {...}
}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is not valid XML. So neither JAXB nor any other technologie can produce a "document" like this.

Comment: A what? Sorry, but what you want is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Well-formedness of an XML:

> There is a single "root" element that contains all the other elements.

Comment: Thank you, I know this, but I have a disgusting demand, and cannot modify the XML